# Generate Java class based on XSD without block substitution?

Tags: java, maven, xsd, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I am getting below error while maven build using jaxb(maven-jaxb2-plugin) compiler

```
A class/interface with the same name "org.somePackage.customer" is already in use.
    Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.util.CodeModelClassFactory.createClass(CodeModelClassFactory.java:121)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.util.CodeModelClassFactory.createClass(CodeModelClassFactory.java:82)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ImplStructureStrategy$1.createClasses(ImplStructureStrategy.java:82)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateClassDef(BeanGenerator.java:437)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.getClazz(BeanGenerator.java:469)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:194)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:166)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:290)
        at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.generateCode(XJC22Mojo.java:70)
```

**What does not work**

```
 <xsd:element name="customer" >
         ........
 </xsd:element>
 <xsd:element name="permanentCustomer" type="customer"/>
```

**What works**

```
<xsd:element name="customer" block="substitution">
 ........
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="permanentCustomer" type="customer"/>
```

I am not sure why removing block attribute creating issue here ?

My guess is jaxb compiler again trying to create the customer class based on element name="permanentCustomer" which it has already created based on element name ="customer". So I don't want to create java object for permanentCustomer while unmarshalling as it has been already created while customer creation. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: First of all, `jaxb:class` customization on the `customer` element of `customer` type will probably work.  
Next, I'm not sure why XJC tries to create a class for the `customer` element. Can you provide a test project which demonstrates this? The best is to PR a test project [here](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/tree/master/tests).

Comment: Thamks lexicore for now I will go ahead with block="substitution". Tested the stuff with this and works fine